# Sort List in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

So I have this C# list:

```
List<DatsWussup.Models.JQGridMessage> gridMessages = new List<DatsWussup.Models.JQGridMessage>();
```

Each `JQGridMessage` has a property called `age`. What's the quickest and most efficient way to sort this list by age (youngest first). Age is an int.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `List<T>` class has a `Sort` method which can be used to in place sort the data.  One overload takes a `Comparison` delegate that can be implemented via an anonymous function.  For example

```
gridMessages.Sort((x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Linq:

```
var sortedEnumerable = gridMessages.OrderBy(m => m.Age);
```

This will return a *new* IEnumerable sorted by age.

Comment: This won't sort the instance of the list but will return a new `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
gridMessages.Sort((m1, m2) => m1.Age.CompareTo(m2.Age));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

```
gridMessages = gridMessages.OrderBy(x => x.age).toList();
```