# Composite sort in List<string> C#

Tags: c#, sorting, tlist

Friends, I have a List like this:

```
var filenames = new List<string> 
{ 
    "150_A_1_A", 
    "150_A_1",  
    "149_2",  
    "149_1",  
    "150_1_A",  
    "150_A_2",  
    "150_2_A"  
};
```

and I need to sort these List in an such way to get the following order:

```
149_1
149_2
150_1_A
150_2_A
150_A_1
150_A_1_A
```

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Use `.Sort()` method Here is already answered question [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573047/sort-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Where `150_A_2` item will be in this order?

Comment: or item `150_10_A`? (I'm guessing your examples are not all that representative of the problem.)

Comment: in your case : 60_1 will come before 100_1 ... right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hers's a LINQ expression doing what you need :

```
var x = filenames.Select(s => new { value = s, splitted = s.Split('_') }).OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.splitted[0]));

for (int i = 1; i < x.Max(s => s.splitted.Length); i++)
{
    var thisI = i;
    x = x.ThenBy(s => thisI >= s.splitted.Length ? null : s.splitted[thisI]);
}

var sorted = x.Select(s => s.value);
```

First I split the strings by '_'

Then I sort the first field numerically.

Finally I sort all the remaing fields alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

`filenames.Sort();` does exactly what you're looking for

If you want lazy execution, you can do this:
`filenames.OrderBy(s => s);`

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa explain why it's not what he's looking for? The output perfectly matches his sample output

Comment: I tried filenames.Sort() before I downvoted. It gives me "150_A_2" as last item, but that's ot what OP is looking for?

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa One would assume it is a shortcoming in his output, unless we are led to believe there is an algorithm named `.SortExceptWhereElementEquals150_A_2()`

Comment: Still an incomplete question cannot really have an answer.

Comment: point taken, removed downvote.