# List Sort how to sort the list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort the list I was looking this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573047/sort-list-in-c-sharp) but I can't figure out why my code doesn't work. I get following error.

> (41:21) There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
> formal parameter 'comparer' of 'List.Sort(int, int,
> IComparer)'

[online compiler](https://rextester.com/AXO97195)

I'm trying to do same as that guy with age but I'm doing on rank. I don't understand where I am going wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;




class PlayerA{
    public PlayerA(){
        playerID = sID++;
    }
    static int sID = 0;
    public int playerID = 0;
    public List<PlayerA> ignore = new List<PlayerA>();
    public int rank = 0;
}





namespace Rextester{
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            List<PlayerA> li = new List<PlayerA>();
            PlayerA[] pl = new PlayerA[10];
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                pl[i] = new PlayerA();
                pl[i].rank = i*2;
            }
            pl[0].rank = 20;
            pl[1].rank = 15;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                li.Add(pl[i]);
            }
            
            li = li.Sort((pl[0], pl[1]), pl[0].rank.CompareTo(pl[1].rank));
            
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(pl[i].rank);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried also

```
li.Sort( (pl[0],pl[1])=>pl[0].rank.CompareTo(pl[1].rank) );
```

but I get:

> (40:35) Syntax error, ',' expected
> (40:37) Syntax error, ',' expected

if I make

```
li.Sort( (pl,pl[0])=>pl.rank.CompareTo(pl.rank) );
```

I get same if I reamove 1 [] like:

```
li.Sort( (pl,pl)=>pl.rank.CompareTo(pl.rank) );
```

I get:

```
(42:23) A local or parameter named 'pl' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
(42:26) The parameter name 'pl' is a duplicate
(42:31) Ambiguity between 'PlayerA' and 'PlayerA'
(42:49) Ambiguity between 'PlayerA' and 'PlayerA'
```

I'm totally blind here I don't understand the basics of this function

```
li.Sort( (x,y)=>x.rank.CompareTo(y.rank) );
```

I don't understand what x or y is it's not pl it's not pl[] what is it I don't understand

ok just for fun I get it as x and y not anything else and it compiled so it should work and I don't understand why it compiled but ok, ... now prblem is it didn't sort it

[online compiler new code](https://rextester.com/TWHVX45962)  witch doesn't sort but compiles where is the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;




class PlayerA{
    public PlayerA(){
        playerID = sID++;
    }
    static int sID = 0;
    public int playerID = 0;
    public List<PlayerA> ignore = new List<PlayerA>();
    public int rank = 0;
}





namespace Rextester{
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            
            List<PlayerA> li = new List<PlayerA>();
            PlayerA[] pl = new PlayerA[10];
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                pl[i] = new PlayerA();
                pl[i].rank = i*2;
            }
            pl[0].rank = 20;
            pl[1].rank = 15;
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                li.Add(pl[i]);
            }
            
            li.Sort( (x,y)=>x.rank.CompareTo(y.rank) );
            
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                Console.WriteLine(pl[i].rank);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're talking about C#, please consider tagging your question with the appropriate language and topics

Comment: uhm I did tag it c#, list and sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the **same** expression as the linked answer:

```
li.Sort( (x,y)=>x.rank.CompareTo(y.rank) );
```

---

The code you posted:

```
li = li.Sort((pl[0], pl[1]), pl[0].rank.CompareTo(pl[1].rank));
```

is completely different from the linked answer. The linked answer uses a *function (delegate)* in lambda form that compares two parameters named `x` and `y` :

```
(x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age)
```

[List.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) doesn't return anything either, as it sorts the list in-place.

What you posted tries to pass a `(PlayerA,PlayerS)` tuple and a `int` to `Sort`. If you write each parameter on a separate line, what you posted is :

```
li = li.Sort(
    (pl[0], pl[1]), 
    pl[0].rank.CompareTo(pl[1].rank)
);
```

`(pl[0], pl[1])` is a tuple containing the first two elements of the list. `pl[0].rank.CompareTo(pl[1].rank` returns the result of comparing two specific list items. No `Sort` overload accepts such parameters. The error tells you that the compiler couldn't find any matching function, and the closest match is lacking some parameters

**Update**

The following code :

```
var list=Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i=>new PlayerA{Rank=i*2}).ToList();
list[0].Rank=20;
list[1].Rank=15;
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",list.Select(x=>x.Rank)));

list.Sort((x,y)=>x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",list.Select(x=>x.Rank)));
```

Prints :

```
20,15,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
4,6,8,10,12,14,15,16,18,20
```

This [dotNetFiddle snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0n95hQ) can be used to run the code and reproduce the results

Comment: li.Sort( (pl[0],pl[1])=>pl[0].rank.CompareTo(pl[1].rank) );          

                should do it but problem is I get:

                (40:35) Syntax error, ',' expected

                (40:37) Syntax error, ',' expected

Comment: No it shouldn't. You keep using *array items* instead of parameter names. Have you tried using the answer's code?

Comment: ok got it I literaly copied it and it compiled but it dint' sort it out I still don't understand why it compiled it

Comment: @MilitaryG Have you tried printing out the list items before and after sorting? `List.Sort` works. I posted an example that shows the list *is* sorted.

Comment: the new code is just updated on the question

Comment: @MilitaryG I just posted an example that shows that the code works. As for what `Sort` does or how it works, did you [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__)? You didn't ask what this code does, you asked why your original attempt failed, even though it was completely different from the documentation and examples

Comment: The documentation explains that this is a [Comparision delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=net-5.0) . A [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) is a function reference. It can point to an existing function or it [can be a lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: yes I saw your online compiler and it works on it but it still donesn't work at mine don't know why.

Comment: @MilitaryG because you haven't used the same code. `List.Sort` isn't a new function. If it didn't work, millions of programmers would notice. Post an *actual example* that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: got it I had pl insteat li